# Trigger Bootstrap modal thats in a component from another template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-bootstrap

I am using [ember-bootstrap](http://www.ember-bootstrap.com/) and their modal component to create a modal on a template. Currently the modal component and the button to trigger it are on the same template, however I want to move the modal to a component so I can keep the template code clean.

**This works**

```
//application/template.hbs
{{#bs-button onClick=(action (mut modal1) true)}}Open Modal{{/bs-button}}

{{#bs-modal-simple open=modal1 title="Simple Dialog" size="sm" onHidden=(action (mut modal1) false)}}
  Hi there
{{/bs-modal-simple}}
```

**This doesn't work**

```
//application/template.hbs
{{#bs-button onClick=(action (mut modal1) true)}}Open Modal{{/bs-button}}
{{my-modal}}

//components/my-modal/template.hbs
{{#bs-modal-simple open=modal1 title="Simple Dialog" size="sm" onHidden=(action (mut modal1) false)}}
  Hi there
{{/bs-modal-simple}}
```

How could I get it so the modal is triggered from the applications template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `my-modal` component is unaware of `modal1` boolean you change in `application.hbs` upon button click to display the modal dialog. What you need to do is passing `modal1` attribute to `my-modal`. Check out the [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/aaa28e54bb8a4a91a0e3523136ab689d?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-modal.hbs). By passing the boolean attribute to `my-modal` component you are now modifying the same boolean both on `application.hbs` and `my-modal.hbs`. (Note that, I updated the twiddle to respect Data Down Action Up principle; so that `modal1` is only updated by `application` and not `my-modal`. `modal1` attribute is now only readonly for `my-modal`).

However; when trying to display modal on a big project and to trigger modal dialog not only from `application.hbs` but from anywhere in the application; what I do is typically creating a service and delegating visibility management of modal dialog to that service. You should consider such an approach if you are to develop something bigger.

Comment: Thank you, that did it. If it comes down to it I will consider using a service.

Comment: @EricGoncalves i updated the answer twiddle to honor data-down action-up. I like it better this way; but if previous option is OK for you; it is fine, too.